# Remove the list for categories children

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I list my categories with [wp_list_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

When there are subcategories, the result/html gives by default :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">category parent</a></li>
  <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="">category children</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I would like to remove the ul list for the catégories children, to have a simple list of categories:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">category parent</a></li>
<li><a href="">category children</a></li>
</ul>
```

Do you know how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using jQuery

```
var innerUl = $(".children").html();
$(".children").remove();
$("ul").append(innerUl);
```

Or you can use [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), it would be a better solution.